# Get images from rss on another domain(then append it)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, append

I want to get images from a flickr rss but this code won't get them.
This is what I got up with after some help from my original qustion here : [Jquery in Internet Explorer: find image problem(works in FF and Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096515/jquery-in-internet-explorer-find-image-problemworks-in-ff-and-chrome)

The problem is getting the data in right format to my web page. 
My page's URL is : zalastax.co.cc/pictures.html

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "js/getflickreasy.php",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).find("item").each(function() {

            var item = $(this), title, description, thumbnail;

            title = item.find("title").text();
            description = item.find("description").text();
            thumbnail = item.find("img").attr("src");
        });
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?
header("content-type: text/xml");
readfile("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=42980910@N02&lang=en-us&format=xml");
?>
```

**Edit:** Mathews code works.
But I have a problem with appending some data.

```
    var currentImage = 0;
//get flicker images from rss.
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=42980910@N02&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
    $(data.items).each(function() {
        var item = this,
            title, description, thumbnail;
        title = item.title;
        description = item.description;
        thumbnail = item.media.m;
        if (currentImage % 3 === 0) {
            $("#apa").append("<p>HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH</p>");
        }
        currentImage++;
        $("#apa").append("<div id=\"div" + currentImage + "\" class=\"imageContainer pictDiv\"><img id=\"img" + currentImage + "\" class=\"bild pictImg\" src=\"" + thumbnail + "\" /></div>");
        $("#bakgrund").append("<img id=\"bkg" + currentImage + "\" class=\"bgrund pictBkg\" src=\"Bilder/polaroid.png\" />");
    });

    $("#bakgrund").append("<img id=\"bkg" + currentImage + "\" class=\"bgrund pictBkg\" src=\"Bilder/polaroid.png\" />");
});
```

This code works in Google Chrome. In Firefox it retrieves the data but don't do the append.
If I try appending something else like simple text Firefox won't append that either.

It works when I'm trying it via jsfiddle.net but it doesn't when trying it via my own webpage.

Comment: This works fine for me in Firefox - http://jsfiddle.net/tBAXV/

Comment: I know, it works when using it via fiddle but it doesn't when using it in my webpage.  I tried with both full source and only this source and it won't append. check it out at http://www.zalastax.co.cc/pictures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without PHP, using JSONP:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=42980910@N02&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
        $(data.items).each(function() {
            var item = this, title, description, thumbnail;
            title = item.title;
            description = item.description;;
            thumbnail = item.media.m;
        });
    });
```

I made a jsFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lb59/).

Comment: Your code works when using it in jsFiddle but when I try it on http://zalastax.co.cc/pictures.html with Firefox and IE it won't create the images. It will do it when using Google Chrome.

Comment: @Zalastax, the DOM isn't loaded yet.  You need to do it inside [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), or your existing `load` handler.

Comment: LoL. I had that in a previous code version but apparently it was lost somewhere on the debugging road. Do you know any website where you can learn how to be skilled at debugging or is it just to know the language really good?

Comment: [`Firebug`](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel) can often be helpful (I looked at your code in the Firebug script panel), but there's no substitute for knowing the language and APIs.

Answer (score 0):

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Easy way to fetch a website and simple interface to load specific data :)